# Test for paired data on categorical variable with >2 levels

Tags: contingency-tables, paired-comparisons, mcnemar-test

I am looking for the appropriate statistical test to compare frequencies over a categorical variable with >2 classes, for paired data (in practice, each individual has been labelled A, B, C or D before and after intervention)...I saw that McNemar test works on 2x2 contingency tables. Is there an equivalent test for a 2 x >2 table?

Comment: `McNemar test works on 2x2`. Please, 1) add `McNemar test` tag to your question or simply find the tag on this site. 2) Point mouse cursor on it. 3) Read the information.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I got confused because using the function `mcnemar.test()` in R on a 2x4 matrix I got an error reporting that the number of rows and columns had to be equal for performing the test. However, I don't find any function in R to perform the McNemar-Bowker test